# Access Server on different subnet

Tags: vpn, firewall, subnet, lan

Dears,
I have a Zyxel USG20 and I defined 2 lans. The first one 192.168.1.xx and the second 192.68.2.xx
on the first I have a secure server with static IP 192.168.1.101
on the second subnet I have my TV 192.168.2.100 and I want to be able to connect to the server and use UPnP.
Is this setup possible? Can you help on this config?

Many thanks

R.